# How to get specified number of character from a string in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
00111100000000010001000000000001
00110100001001000000000000000000
00100100000000100000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000001100
00100100000000100000000000001010
00000000000000000000000000001100
```

Given this machine code, I need to just get the first line (32) characters, so that I can convert it back into MIPS instructions. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the first line of code and store it into a register. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the first line, and the next lines after that? I was given a hint to try using the sll or srl instructions, but when I do that, i do not see any change in the code.

```
#File to be read from
file: .asciiz "bincode1.txt"
#place to store contents of file
buffer: .space 1024

    .text

#Open the file
li $v0, 13  #system call to open the file
la $a0, file    #load address of the file and store in a0
li $a1, 0   #a1 is reserved for a line in the text file
li $a2, 0
syscall     #opens the file
move $s0, $v0   #save file descriptor 

#Read the file
li $v0, 14  #system call to read from the file
move $a0, $s0   #put the file name into a0
la $a1, buffer  #address of the buffer to read
li $a2, 1024
syscall

#Close the file
li $v0, 16  #system call to close the file
move $a0, $s0   #file name to close
syscall

#print contents of buffer to verify it copied correctly 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, buffer
syscall

#la $t1, buffer
srl $t2, $a0, 32

li $v0, 4
la $a1, ($t2)
syscall
```

The file bincode1.txt has the previous 6 lines of machine code. I get an error if I try to shift it by 32, and I know this is incorrect, but I am not sure what to do from here. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: On my code, I forgot to copy over the .data portion above the first line. That should be there as well.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix it, look for "edit" under tags. Just don't change the code/question **after** it was answered, at that point just add additional paragraph with any errata or further information, so the answer will be still relevant to original question. Before you get any answer: feel free to improve your question as much as you want. It looks reasonable already, but you may still add information what environment you use (what assembler, debugger, how the command line building executable looks) and make sure anyone with same env can copy/paste+run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint after printing content for verification, open the memory view to point at address `buffer`, you will see the content of file was read as consecutive byte values, which are ASCII encoded to form a text.

So the actual byte values are:

```
buffer: .byte 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, ... , 48, 49, <EOL>, 48, 48, ...`
```

Where `<EOL>` is end of line (probably `13` on MIPS, maybe just `10` or both), and `48` is value of ASCII character `'0'` and `49` is value of ASCII character `'1'`.

You can see the same bytes when you view the content of "bincode1.txt" file in some hexa-viewer.

So to convert 32 ASCII characters into single 32b value you have to loop through 32 bytes, set single bit to 0/1 according to the character read (`'0' (48)`/`'1' (49)`, decide how to handle wrong input with non-0/1 digit, for simplicity you may just do `and char,1` to get 0/1 bit from any byte, even non-digit one, and ignore incorrect files), and merge those bits together.

The easiest way to merge bits together is IMO to set some temporary register to zero ahead of loop `t0 = 0`, then after reading next character from `buffer` you first shift all its bits to left by one `sll $t0, $t0, 1`, and then set the least significant bit with the one read from buffer (bitwise `OR` may be helpful, after that `and char,1` to extract only lowest (right-most) bit from char). Loop 32 times through this, and voila, you have 32b number in `t0` (as you are shifting left, the first char read will end in the left-most bit, which is very likely what you wanted).

Then you can print it as number value, to verify the conversion produced correct result.

Hint: try to visualize your input and output data, and how those bits are relevant to each other, play a bit with debugger to see how it can display the memory and register values (maybe it allows several different formats/grouping, which can make it easier for you to check particular values in different situations, like when checking ASCII data it's usually good to see separate bytes, but for example `word` sized numbers are better to be viewed when 4 bytes are grouped into single value). Then try to imagine how you would treat the input data to calculate the expected output, and write the algorithm for it.